# webrequest and proxies

Tags: c#, proxy, httpwebrequest

I'm connect to a server using HttpWebRequest, and I set the proxy:

```
request.Proxy = new WebProxy("ipaddress", 8080);
request.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
```

However this doesn't work, one of the reasons being getting timed out. The problem is that because auto redirection is true, the request gets redirected a few times and some of those redirects require port 443.

When I use the same proxy settings in Firefox (SSL proxy is empty), it works fine.

Is it possible to get it to work using webrequests?

Comment: Here everything is based on the proxy you using, Process will get delay if you r using public or open proxies and it also depends on the type of proxy (Http, HTTPS, Socks4,socks4a, socks5) . Check those, after having clear idea about proxies you can identify whats your problems actually is ...

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".